# Quicksort algorithm not sorting in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I coded a quicksort algorithm that I got from [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort) site.

I followed the first algorithm and this is what my code looks like:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> copy;

public static ArrayList<Integer> concatenate(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b, ArrayList<Integer> c) {
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        result.add(a.get(i));
    for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
        result.add(b.get(i));
    for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
        result.add(c.get(i));
    return result;
}

public static void quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
    ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> equal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    if(a.size() > 1) {
        int pivot = a.get(rand.nextInt(a.size()-1));
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if(a.get(i) < pivot)
                less.add(a.get(i));
            if(a.get(i) == pivot)
                equal.add(a.get(i));
            if(a.get(i) > pivot)
                greater.add(a.get(i));
        }
        quickSort(less);
        quickSort(greater);
        a = concatenate(less, equal, greater);
    }
    copy = a;
}
```

For some reason when I print copy in main I get what looks like this:

```
Before: 2, 5, 9, 3, 3, 2, 0, 8, 1, 5
After : 0, 1, 2, 5, 9, 3, 3, 2, 8, 5
```

Is there a problem on my code or the algorithm?

Comment: Have you debugged the function to identify the problematic lines?

Comment: Notice that you can skip those for-loops in `concatenate()` by simply using `list.addAll(anotherList)`.

Comment: Yes. There seems to be no problematic lines

Comment: There are several problems with the code presented, whatever algorithm may be yours. Rethink instance variables, let alone class variable. Use "foreach"-loops, "if-else_if-else", genericity, …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Java example in the link you provided, there are a few dissimilarities between your code and the example.

Your function does not return the list, it returns void, try making the function return a list, then assign the return of this to less and more, rather than just calling "quickSort(less)" or "quickSort(more)". E.g. in the example:

```
// Recursively sort sublists
    less = quickSort(less);
    more = quickSort(more);
```

Perhaps yours is just calling the sort once, so only sorts one part of the list, it certainly seems so from your output anyway. Make sure you are returning the lists each time and not just sorting each list recursively and then not linking it to the lists from the previous calls. After all the recursive calls of quickSort, it returns to the final line of the first call, and simply overwrites the value of a and concatenates less, equal and greater, ignoring all the previous work done in the iterations, so you're just getting the results of the first sort.

Comment: I changed the code and it works! Sorry if the question is badly written

Comment: No worries. Might want to read into recursion a bit more so you understand exactly how it works. If this answer helped, can you mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Marked. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of `quickSort` function there is an overriding of the `copy` list that will be performed in each recursive call, thus losing all the changes.

```
copy = a;
```

As dahui says, try making a quickSort function that returns the sorted list. You can copy and paste this code in your IDE and hopefully it will work :) (I pulled out the Random var to prevent its creation in each recursive call).

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Quicksort {

    // For selecting random pivot
    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> concatenate(ArrayList<Integer> a, ArrayList<Integer> b, ArrayList<Integer> c) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            result.add(a.get(i));
        for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
            result.add(b.get(i));
        for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++)
            result.add(c.get(i));
        return result;
    }


    public static ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> less = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> greater = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> equal = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if(a.size() > 1) {
            int pivot = a.get(rand.nextInt(a.size()-1));

            for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
                if(a.get(i) < pivot)
                    less.add(a.get(i));
                if(a.get(i) == pivot)
                    equal.add(a.get(i));
                if(a.get(i) > pivot)
                    greater.add(a.get(i));
            }
            less    = quickSort(less);
            greater = quickSort(greater);
            a = concatenate(less, equal, greater);
        }

        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("*** Starting Quicksort ***\n"); 

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2, 5, 9, 3, 3, 2, 0, 8, 1, 5}));
        System.out.println("Unsorted:\t" + numbers);
        System.out.println("Sorted:  \t" + quickSort(numbers));


        System.out.println("\n*** Sorting finalized. Have a good day!");
    }

}
```